# Почему образовалась ошибка на этапе выполнения в заголовочном файле memory?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Можно ли работать с for_each как с обычным циклом и как можно выйти из него(break не работает),в ифе сравниваются две переменные типа double ,не знаю из за чего она может тут быть.Цикл по вектору .
[[image: сама ошибка![][1]]]

https://github.com/vantig/SoundRecordingProject можно скомпилить в VS

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseTrack> Playlist::findMusicinRange(double start, double finish)
{
    std::for_each(this->music.begin(),this-> music.end(), [start,finish](auto temp) 
        {
            double x=temp->getDuration();
            if (x >= start && x<=finish )
            {
                std::cout << temp;
                return temp;
                
            }
            
        });
    std::shared_ptr<BaseTrack>null;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код и ошибки текстом, а не скринами

Comment: `for_each` ни разу не цикл, а функция... Пока нет [компилируемого самодостаточного примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), остается только гадать. Может, проблема в `getDuration()`?...

Comment: Короче [mre], [ask]

Comment: @Harry Прикрепил ссылку на весь проект ,данная функция возвращает поле типа double

Comment: Посмотрел внимательнее... Поясните, что вы хотите добиться этим вызовом `for_each` - просто вывести все значения на экран?.. Просто пытаюсь понять, зачем у вас `return temp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй [*Ranged-based*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) версию цикла `for` и будет тебе счастье:

```
for(auto& track: this->music) {
  double duration = track->getDuration();
  if (duration >= start && duration<=finish ) {
    std::cout << track;
    break; /* или return track; */
  }
}
```

Если очень хочется воспользоваться каким-нибудь STL'евским алгоритмом, то тут больше подойдёт [`find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
auto trackIt = std::find_if(this->music.begin(), this-> music.end(),
  [start,finish](auto track)->bool {
    double duration = track->getDuration();
    return (start<=duration && duration<=finish );
  });

if (trackIt) {
  std::cout << *trackIt;
  return *trackIt
} else {
  return std::shared_ptr<BaseTrack>();
}
```

> Можно ли работать с for_each как с обычным циклом

Нет, нельзя. Как уже сказано в комментарияхе, [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) — это не цикл, не специальная конструкция языка, а просто функция, которая принимает в качестве последнего аргумента функтор. Типовая реализация примерно такая:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
constexpr UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        f(*first);
    }
    return f; // implicit move since C++11
}
```

> Почему образовалась ошибка на этапе выполнения в заголовочном файле memory?

Потому что не все ветки функтора, передаваемого `std::for_each` возвращают значение. А это UB. Компилятор должен был выругаться по этому поводу. Если говорить практически, то когда трека с нужной продолжительностью в коллекции не находится функтор возвращает мусорное значение для которого потом вызывается деструктор `~shared_ptr()`. Вообще говоря, функтор передаваемый в `std::for_each` и не должен возвращать никакого значения, но большинство реализации это проглатывают.

Comment: спасибо тебе огромное за столь подробный ответ ,очень помог.